# XML parse nested node using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I'm trying to get all the PV value in each PMT section.  How would I do this using XmlDocument?

I can get all the PV and all the PMT using

```
XmlNodeList PMTList = reader.SelectNodes("/PARM/PMT");
XmlNodeList PVList = reader.SelectNodes("/PARM/PMT/PV");

foreach (XmlNode node in PMTList)
{
   Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("NM").Value);
}
foreach (XmlNode node in PVList)
{
   Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("PV").Value);
}
```

but I can't figure out how to get it per a section.  Get all the PVs with the PMT.  Blow is an example of what I want and my xml.  PLEASE help! Thanks!

EXAMPLE:

```
SOCIETY CODE
  SPE
  OTC
  ARMA
  ...

CONTENT_TYPE
   Conference Paper
   Journal Paper
   ...
```

Sample XML

```
<PARM>
    <PC>0</PC>
    <PMT NM="SOCIETY_CODE" DN="Publisher" IR="0" T="0">
        <PV V="SPE" L="" H="" C="444"/>
        <PV V="OTC" L="" H="" C="24"/>
        <PV V="ARMA" L="" H="" C="11"/>
        <PV V="SEG" L="" H="" C="11"/>
        <PV V="IPTC" L="" H="" C="8"/>
        <PV V="NACE" L="" H="" C="1"/>
     </PMT>
     <PMT NM="CONTENT_TYPE" DN="Content Type" IR="0" T="0">
        <PV V="Conference Paper" L="" H="" C="468"/>
        <PV V="Journal Paper" L="" H="" C="30"/>
        <PV V="Other" L="" H="" C="1"/>
     </PMT>
</PARM>
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using XmlDocument instead of XDocument? LINQ to XML makes XML handling much simpler.

Comment: Maybe he's on .net 2.0, @Jon.

Comment: @DarrenKopp: That's why I asked - he may be, or he may not be...